# Flutter: how to test the scroll

Tags: testing, scroll, flutter

I have a ListView.builder with a ScrollController as controller:

```
  _buildListView(state) => ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _draw(index, state),
        itemCount: state.count
        controller: _scrollController,
      );
```

I add a listener to the controller:

```
  View() {
    _scrollController.addListener(_onScroll);
  }
```

I would like to test the _onScroll function:

```
 void _onScroll() {
    final maxScroll = _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent;
    final currentScroll = _scrollController.position.pixels;
    if (maxScroll - currentScroll <= _scrollThreshold) {
      _bloc.dispatch(Fetch());
    }
  }
```

But I don't know how can I test it. This is what I tried so far:

```
  testWidgets('Should test the scroll',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
await tester.pumpWidget(generateApp());
    await tester.pump();
    await tester.drag(find.byType(ListView), const Offset(0.0, -300));
    await tester.pump();
...

)}
```

but it doesn't call at all that function.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can create a [TestGesture](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/flutter_test/TestGesture-class.html) in your tests and perform a scroll that way.

```
final gesture = await tester.startGesture(Offset(0, 300)); //Position of the scrollview
await gesture.moveBy(Offset(0, -300)); //How much to scroll by
await tester.pump();
```

Comment: Should I use only these lines or do more? Because only like this doesn't work

Comment: Need to close parenthesis on the first line, but otherwise works!

Comment: I'm trying to use this snippet in order to test a PageView scroll, but it seems is not working:  `gesture = await tester.startGesture(Offset(500, 500));
    await gesture.moveBy(Offset(-100, 0));`

Comment: I had to add `await gesture.up();` before the pump call for the scrolling to work.

Comment: this solution works for me in iOS simulator but not in physical iPhone , for physical iphone I need to follow this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67990754/4245112

Answer (score 23):

for those using the new `flutter_test` lib, we also have the `dragUntilVisible` method:

```
await tester.dragUntilVisible(
    find.text('Earn mana!'), // what you want to find
    find.byKey(ValueKey('OnboardingCarousel')), // widget you want to scroll
    const Offset(-250, 0), // delta to move
);
```

Comment: this works for me in both ios simulator and physical iphone

Answer (score 11):

If you pass the key parameter to the builder:

```
ListView.builder(key: Key('ListViewKey'),...);
```

Then finding by key:

```
await tester.drag(find.byKey(Key('ListViewKey')), const Offset(0.0, -300));
await tester.pump();
```

Will work.

Answer (score 5):

Scrolling can be tested using `dragUntilVisible`, which scrolls the widget till it gets visible on screen, just make sure the right delta is added for moving it vertically or horizontally.

```
 final expectedWidget = find.byText("Find me!");

  await tester.dragUntilVisible(
      expectedWidget, // what you want to find
      find.byType(ListView),
      // widget you want to scroll
      const Offset(0, 500) // delta to move
     );
```

Answer (score 3):

As an alternative it's also possible to search for the ListView widget itself and retrieve its scroll controller to manipulate it directly:

```
final listView = tester.widget<ListView>(find.byType(ListView));
final ctrl = listView.controller;
ctrl.jumpTo(ctrl.offset + 300);
await tester.pumpAndSettle(duration);
```

Answer (score 2):

I highly recommend you to pay attention in the "Cartesian plane" of your screen/dragging movement.

Let me explain:

1. You should use:
   await tester.drag(keyCartItemProduct1, Offset(-500.0, 0.0));
2. However, your "Offset" Command, must obey the same "Cartesian direction" than your Dragging.

2.1) Therefore: (The command Offset uses Cartesian 'directions') - lets see:
a) Left Dragging: Offset(-500.0, 0.0)
b) Right Dragging: Offset(+500.0, 0.0)
c) Up Dragging: Offset(0.0, +500.0)
d) Down Dragging: Offset(0.0, -500.0)

Answer (score 0):

For my case I tried both `scrollUntilVisible` and `dragUntilVisible`, but none worked. (maybe because of the nested scrollable widget). This worked for me for scrolling to the bottom of the list:

```dart
await tester.drag(
  find.byType(ListTile).first,
  const Offset(0, -100),
);
```

Remember to run `await tester.pumpAndSettle()` after that.